# How to walk through tiles of infinity extent grid given only single integer parameter?

Tags: grid, iteration, tile

The walking should include tiles in circular path to make sure all tiles around the center are walked as shown in gif.

The grid is infinite extent, so I cannot use width nor height. They will make no benefit to be used however because I need to walk in order of how much the tile is near to the center.

[black represents the center (startup tile) red is the displaced tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWy3s.gif)

the alghorithm head can be like this:

```
walk(center: TileIndex, d: Int)
    if d == 0
        return center
    else
       ...
```

I need help to do the rest. I'm also curios if this even possible. I've searched about this but couldn't find somone who has a similar problem.